# Conflict between localStorage and actual value

Tags: reactjs

The color of my components change based on day/night mode and this is locally saved as an object in nightMode in case the app is closed. The issue is the color is only locally saved once the user presses a button to switch to day/night mode. Therefore when the app is first opened nightMode is given a value, but localStorage is still null. So when useEffect runs it overrides my nightMode value and makes it null. How can I overcome this issue.

**Initial value:**

```
const [isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(false); 

const [nightMode, setNightMode] = React.useState({
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    bannerText: "#FFFFFF",
    listText: "#000000",
    banner: "#55BAF1",
    inputBackground: "FFFFFF",
  });
```

**Pseudo version of the function which locally saves the color:**

```
function nightMode(){
   const light = #FFFFFF
   const dark = #55BAF1
   
   if(isNightMode){
      setNightMode(dark);
      localStorage.setItem("startupMode", JSON.stringify(dark));
   }
   else(isNightMode){
      setNightMode(light);
      localStorage.setItem("startupMode", JSON.stringify(light));
   }
}
```

**Cause of the problem (sets night mode to null):**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const sessionSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode")) || [];
  setNightMode(sessionSettings);
}, []);
```

Comment: you mean `setNightMode` sets it to `null`? I mean `setNightMode(null)`? btw why do you have `else(value to observe)`? Didn't you mean `else if(...)`? or just write `if(nightMode) {...} else {...}`

Comment: +1 if you assign `[]` as a `fallback\default` value that converts to `boolean true` so `isNightMode` will be true. just try `!![]` this will yield `true`

Comment: The issue isn't the isNightMode, it's the object nightMode. On startup I give nightMode an initial value but in localStorage it's still null. So the useEffect runs and sets nightMode to a null object. I'm trying to figure out a way to define the nightMode object in localStorage on the initial start up.

Comment: Did you try removing `isNightMode` from your else?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having the useEffect store a value if it's null. Kind of a brute force solution to the problem but it works

```
React.useEffect(() => {

    const currSavedColor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode")) || [];

    const lightMode = {
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    }

    if(currSavedColor.banner !== "#FFFFFF"){
      localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(lightMode));
      const sessionSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode")) || [];
      setNightMode(sessionSettings);
    }
    else{
      const sessionSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode")) || [];
      setNightMode(sessionSettings);
    }
  }, []);
```